# Create Design Time Data in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

My MainWindow.xaml loads very slowly, so I'm trying to create a design-time data for that. I have checked some websites on the net and tried to create design-time data but it gives error.
Here is my part of xaml, the rest is wpf elements :

```
<Window x:Class="CodeFirstMVVM.App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CodeFirstMVVM.App.ViewModels"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CodeFirstMVVM.App.ViewModels"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=model:Ogrenci, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=OgrenciView}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="900">
```

I get the error in this line :

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=model:Ogrenci, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

And the errors are :

> ```
> Error 1   The namespace prefix "model" is not defined.    
> Error 2   Ogrenci is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
> ```

The DesignTimeViewModel is under CodeFirstMVVM.App, and it is simply an empty class with an empty constructor. Can you tell me how to create a design time data in a healthy way? I'm really stuck with this.

Comment: Is it in the same assembly? Also, do you have some errors in the code that you prevent it from compiling?

Comment: @dkozl there is one error and it is in the question. I didn't understand if it is assembly or not..